# Optimizing iOS App File Size

Tags: ios

What are other work arounds to optimize the overall file size of an iOS App? I have done, making my images into PNG-8 though.

What I just noticed in my Project is, some of the files added are external classes (Classes from Github that consists of .h and .m)

would it be better if I will just referenced these classes? Even if one module is just 2 Files?

Comment: What do you mean by 'just referencing'?

Comment: @H2CO3 like that of three20, if you're familiar? Basically, I add them in my Project but I wont copy them inside, I'll just add their paths in my Project's Header Search Paths

Comment: That won't make the app smaller, since you'll need to compile the implementation files anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing classes works only for header files, you will need to add the static library in your project. this static library will contain the compiled version of your .m files,

You could compile some of your classes into static libraries and then insert them to your project, however i dont think it will decrease the project size a lot, so my suggestion is to not do that

Comment: thanks, maybe I should take a review with my images, I didn't know also that compiling classes into libraries wouldn't help a lot in compression